# Visual Studio Code error-"The term 'make.exe' is not recognized"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

Although I have installed "make" and its directory is global (I can execute it from cmd and PS). When executing any make in vsc terminal I get error:

```
PS C:\Users\b_wik\Dokumenty\Coding\PersProj\tempAi> make
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
 of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have installed vsc extension to operate the make "Makefile Tools", yet I'm a beginner and I don't understand most.

Comment: at a guess you'll need to restart your pc to fully propagate environment variable changes

Comment: Hard to say for sure what went wrong. What happens when you open a command prompt and type make?

Comment: Did you install [msys2](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and have that install MinGW like the VSCode instructions tell you? Did you logout and log back in after doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was simple "Have you restarted it?" case. As said before, global directory changes needed PC restart to work.

It wasn't problem with neither vsc nor make program.

Comment: This is a bit of how environment variables work. A new child process inherits the current state of the environment that the parent process has. However if the child is already running it doesn't see a change in an environment variable that happened on the OS.

Comment: You don't need to restart the PC, just the program that needs to read the changed environment.